# Error when running Google Sheets function using Apps Script API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-apps-script, google-api, google-oauth, google-auth-library-ruby

I am attempting to run a function on a Google Sheet using the Apps Script API in a Ruby on Rails application. The purpose is to execute a function on a Google Sheet, but I'm encountering an error during this process.

Upon reviewing the Google Apps Script API documentation, it is stated that using a Service Account for the Apps Script APIs is not supported. In response, I attempted to authenticate using OAuth 2.0. However, even after using OAuth 2.0 for authentication, I encountered a 401 Unauthorized error when attempting to run the script.

I need assistance with authorizing the Apps Script API and running the script. Can you please review the code and provide guidance on how to achieve this?

**Code:**

```
require 'google/apis/drive_v3'
require 'sinatra'
require 'googleauth'
require 'googleauth/stores/redis_token_store'

client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file('lib/get_property_data/client_secret.json')
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
token_store=  Google::Auth::Stores::RedisTokenStore.new(redis: Redis.new)
authorizer = Google::Auth::WebUserAuthorizer.new(client_id, scope, token_store, '/oauth2callback')

service = Google::Apis::ScriptV1::ScriptService.new
service.client_options.application_name = 'Application name'
service.authorization = authorizer

request = Google::Apis::ScriptV1::ExecutionRequest.new(function: 'testFunction', parameters: ['sheet_id'])
script_id = 'xxxxxxx'

response  = service.run_script(script_id, request)
```

**Error:**

```
Caught error Unauthorized
Error - #<Google::Apis::AuthorizationError: Unauthorized status_code: 401 header: #<HTTP::Message::Headers:0x00007f806c517978 @http_version="1.1", @body_size=0, @chunked=false, @request_method="POST", @request_uri=#<Addressable::URI:0x3fc03926f794 URI:https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/1BrWLyFp4L0Q-00sZekntFTsZzed_4TLesPQYUSDWx-AbRe4EVEGd5-DW:run?>, @request_query=nil, @request_absolute_uri=nil, @status_code=401, @reason_phrase="Unauthorized", @body_type=nil, @body_charset=nil, @body_date=nil, @body_encoding=#<Encoding:UTF-8>, @is_request=false, @header_item=[["WWW-Authenticate", "Bearer realm=\"https://accounts.google.com/\""], ["Vary", "Origin"], ["Vary", "X-Origin"], ["Vary", "Referer"], ["Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8"], ["Content-Encoding", "gzip"], ["Date", "Wed, 20 Sep 2023 12:27:41 GMT"], ["Server", "ESF"], ["Cache-Control", "private"], ["X-XSS-Protection", "0"], ["X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN"], ["X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff"], ["Alt-Svc", "h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000"], ["Transfer-Encoding", "chunked"]], @dumped=false> body: "{\n  \"error\": {\n    \"code\": 401,\n    \"message\": \"Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.\",\n    \"errors\": [\n      {\n        \"message\": \"Login Required.\",\n        \"domain\": \"global\",\n        \"reason\": \"required\",\n        \"location\": \"Authorization\",\n        \"locationType\": \"header\"\n      }\n    ],\n    \"status\": \"UNAUTHENTICATED\",\n    \"details\": [\n      {\n        \"@type\": \"type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo\",\n        \"reason\": \"CREDENTIALS_MISSING\",\n        \"domain\": \"googleapis.com\",\n        \"metadata\": {\n          \"service\": \"script.googleapis.com\",\n          \"method\": \"google.apps.script.v1.ScriptExecution.Execute\"\n        }\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n}\n">

Retrying after authentication failure
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):37
Google::Apis::AuthorizationError (Unauthorized)
```

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to effectively authenticate using OAuth 2.0 and resolve the issue with the run_script method.

Comment: @dbugger In the first approach, we're using a service account for authentication. However, the Google documentation advises against using a service account for the apps script API. That's why I'm opting for the second method, which involves authentication through OAuth. I believe it's better to proceed with this second approach.

Comment: FYI, I don't really know much about Ruby on Rails, but just so to help, can you walk us through the entire authentication process you followed? Based on this [documentation](

[https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/enable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/enable)

) you may need to enable the API services for both Sheets and Apps Script API and generate the needed credentials file.

Comment: Yes, I have followed all the steps to enable the Apps script API and also generated the credentials, downloaded the json file having client id, client secret and other attributes but still encountering issues when trying to run the APIs. :(

Comment: In regards to the credentials file you have generated, have you generated the credentials file for Service Account or for  Web Applications?

Comment: I have generated for both, I tried to authenticate using a service account but encountered difficulties. Upon consulting the documentation, I discovered a cautionary note stating that 'The Apps Script API doesn't work with service accounts.'. Then, I proceeded to use OAuth web application credentials as outlined in my problem description.